# Conocer el tamaño de una key en un objeto json

Tags: javascript, html5, json

estuve intentando lo siguiente:

```
for(var i = 0; i < obj.breves.length; i++){
                document.getElementById('brevesCaract').innerHTML += obj.breves[i];
}
```

al principio me funciono y en la consola si me inidicaba el tamaño del key, ahora lo volví a correr y en la consola me sale que no se puede leer la propiedad "length" de un tipo no definido de xmlhttprequest..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la documentación de mzn como de w3schools indican que si funciona la propiedad length, también intente usar el for-in que indican y no se muestra en el documento y en la consola no se indica que haya algún error en cuanto a ello (el código es:

```
for (var i in obj.breves) {
  x += obj.breves[i];
}
document.getElementById("brevesCaract").innerHTML = x;
```

)

¿talvez hay otra forma de saber el tamaño para recorrer el key?

el archivo .json es:

```
{
    "imgP" : "../LAPTOP/ASUS_VIVOBOOK_15_K513EA/FOTO_P1.jpg",
    "min1" : "../LAPTOP/ASUS_VIVOBOOK_15_K513EA/FOTO_G1.jpg",
    "min2" : "../LAPTOP/ASUS_VIVOBOOK_15_K513EA/FOTO_G2.jpg",
    "min3" : "../LAPTOP/ASUS_VIVOBOOK_15_K513EA/FOTO_G3.jpg",
    "min4" : "../LAPTOP/ASUS_VIVOBOOK_15_K513EA/FOTO_G4.jpg",
    "tituloProd" : "ASUS VIVOBOOK 15 k513EA",
    "breves" : ["<li>Intel® Core ™ i3 1115G4</li>",
                "<li>Intel® UHD Gráficos</li>",
                "<li>8 GB DDR4 3200MHz SDRAM</li>",
                "<li>256 GB SSD M.2 PCIe®</li>"
               ],
    "fichaTec" : ["<li>Sistema operativo</li>",
                      "<li>Windows 10 Home</li>",
                      "<li>Procesador</li>",
                      "<li>Intel® Core ™ i3 1115G4</li>",
                      "<li>2 núcleos / 4 hilos</li>",
                      "<li>6M Cache, hasta 4.10 GHz</li>"
                  ]
}
```

de lo que tengo entendido la estructura esta bien en el archivo y no debería de surgirme problemas pero me pasa todo lo contrario.

Comment: ¿la propiedad de tu objeto `breves` es un objeto? Es decir, `obj.breves`. La única manera que yo conozco para sacar un length de un objeto es usando Object.keys y luego sí aplicando length

Comment: si, se supone que en el obj ya guardo todo el archivo.json donde se especifica el "breves" y se supone que es un array pero no lo toma en cuenta mientras que otros keys los lee sin problema y los puedo mostrar en el htm mediante .innerText o .innerHtml de ser necesario

Comment: bueno, entonces creo que es algo que debes colocar en tu pregunta para poder ayudarte. Es decir, muestra lo que te llega en tu obj, cómo está estructurado y demás.

Comment: listo ya le puedes visualizar

Comment: Probé tu objeto. Con ese debería funcionar. Lo único que se me ocurre es que en esa propiedad de tu objeto, no exista o tenga valor undefined en algunos casos.

Comment: Coloca la parte de donde traes el objeto que quieres recorrer

Comment: Donde lo quiero recorrer es el código de la primera parte , y si te sirve de algo el obj = new XMLHttpRequest(); después de esto ya pongo otra línea donde esta lo del título  y es: document.getElementById('tituloProducto').innerText = datos.tituloProd;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funciona con el for-in solo que me había olvidado de crear la variable i

```
var i, res = "";
```

antes de consultar

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {...}
```

aplicando lo que se muestra en https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp, si me funcionó y ya puedo visualizar el contenido en brevesCaract como también en fichaTec.